# How to write behat feature testcase for already filled element?

Tags: javascript, behat

I am new to Behat. I have written some basic scenarios in behat feature. 
e.g

```
When I fill in "abc@xyz.com" for "edit-name--2"
      And I fill in "password" for "edit-pass--2"
      And I press "Log in"
    Then I should see "User profile page"
```

Next, I want to check with already filled textbox, already checked checkbox, already choosed radio option, already selected select option on next form pages journey.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Mink you can check MinkContext for other definitions or you can run behat with -di option in a bash console and grep by a keyword.
Example: behat -di | grep checked

Another thing you can do is define new steps. Extend MinkContext and define steps like:
the element "selector" should be checked
the "selector" should have value "value"